# What are sex linked traits?

Tags: genetics, homework, human-genetics

Which of the two definitions of `sex-linked trait` is correct?

- Traits controlled by genes present on the non-homologous region of sex chromosomes are called sex-linked traits.
- Bodily traits controlled by genes present on the non-homologous regions of sex chromosomes are called sex-linked traits. Here by bodily traits I mean traits that are not involved with sex of an organism.

I read the first definition in the book [Competition Science Vision](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=CLn7QrPutxcC&pg=PT59&dq=sex%20linked%20traits&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwik5JXti_vMAhWJv48KHQMsBZQQ6AEIJDAC#v=onepage&q=sex%20linked%20traits&f=false)and also from [Instant notes genetics](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=xGGWpdzT-WoC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=sex&f=false) (page 163).
The following is an excerpt from the latter

> Sex linkage is not displayed by genes which map to a small segment of X chromosome, the pseudoautosomal region, the part of X chromosome that pairs with Y chromosome in meiosis.

The second definition is made up but sounds potentially intuitive to me.

Comment: What do you mean by "traits that are not involved with sex"? Do you mean traits that are unrelated to (primary or secondary) sexual organs?

Comment: Yes that is what I meant

Comment: I edited your post. Feel free to roll-back. If you agree that the format is much more pleasant to read than before then you can inspire yourself for future posts and try to always use a pleasant format for the readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first definition is correct.

*A sex-linked trait is a trait affected by a locus on a sex chromosome.*

If you [google sex-linked trait](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=sex-link%20trait), you will find this same definition (not the exact same words) over and over again.

The definition of sex-linked trait is NOT restricted to traits that are not unrelated to primary or secondary sexual organs. Any phenotypic trait can be sex-linked as long as the causal locus is on a sexual chromosome.

Comment: "a locus that is present in individuals of only one sex..."  isn't that wrong? Genes on the X are sex linked and therefore present in both sexes

Comment: Yes, you are right that was wrong! I edited it. Thanks.

Comment: @Remi.b What are X-Y linked traits then? Are they what the book says, traits controlled by genes present on homologous regions of sex chromosomes?

Comment: yes, traits causes by genes present on NON-homologous (you said the opposite in your comment) sequence on the X or Y chromosome. In case you did not know the non-homologuous sequence of X or Y chromosome.

Answer (score 1):

Sex linked traits are those controlled by genes on the sex chromosomes, regardless of whether or not they are related to reproduction. This can be the major (e.g. X or Z) or minor (e.g. Y or W) sex chromosomes.

> "Sex linkage applies to genes that are located on the sex chromosomes. These genes are considered sex-linked because their expression and inheritance patterns differ between males and females." - [link](http://learn.genetics.utah.edu/content/pigeons/sexlinkage/)

Note. Most traits are polygenic thus some of the causal genes may be sex linked, and others on the autosomes. Phenotypic traits can therefore have varying degrees of sex linkage.